# hyrbid app open another app using js

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

Trying to open another app within mine (hybrid) using mobilefirst 7.0. Nothing happens when i click either link. In a mobile browser link #2 opens up a webpage. But that's not what I want. Looking to open up facebook within my app for this example. Thanks.

```
Enter a package name: <input type="text" value="com.SFStaff" id="packageName"/>
<button onclick="openExternalApp()">Open External Application</button>
<script>
function openExternalApp() {
    var parameter = null;
    if (WL.Client.getEnvironment() == WL.Environment.ANDROID) {
        parameter = $('#packageName').val();
    }

    cordova.exec(onSuccess, onFailure, "OpenExternalAppPlugin", "openApp", [parameter]);
}

function onSuccess() {
    WL.Logger.info("App successfully opened");
}

function onFailure() {
    WL.Logger.info("App failed opening");
}
</script>
```

In the config.xml

```
<feature name="OpenExternalApp">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.Student.OpenExternalApp" />
</feature>
```

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of existing questions about this topic, some with example projects.  Why not take a look.

- [IBM Worklight - How to launch another app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20612326/ibm-worklight-how-to-launch-another-app)
- [Is there any way to launch one application from another application in android and ios using worklight 6.2 or phonegap hybrid applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319582/is-there-any-way-to-launch-one-application-from-another-application-in-android-a)
- [Worklight(6.1v) hybrid app - need to open other application from my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273233/worklight6-1v-hybrid-app-need-to-open-other-application-from-my-app)
- [Worklight - Open a Native application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831679/worklight-open-a-native-application)
- [How to open the pre installed app from the another hybrid application using worklight and ionic framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33719344/how-to-open-the-pre-installed-app-from-the-another-hybrid-application-using-work)

Comment: Using your example I am getting D/PluginManager(19326): exec() call to unknown plugin: OpenExternalAppPlugin

Comment: The error means your project is not correctly setup with the plugin. You can check the worklight documentation how to setup a project with a Cordova plugin. I believe you likely did not put it in the correct place.

Comment: Got it thanks! There was issue with naming convention and that I didn't realize I had to add the java and config to both native, nativeResources folders.

One issue though it that these updates are not getting direct push updates to the application. I had to export and install a new apk in order for them to take effect. Can you advise?

Comment: The plug-in is copied from the nativeResources folder into the native folder during build-time.

Comment: One issue though it that these updates are not getting direct push updates to the application. I had to export and install a new apk in order for them to take effect. Can you advise?

Comment: These are native changes; Direct Update applies only the web resources (HTML, JS, CSS).